# Can't image mask with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, image-masking

I've been trying to mask an image for a website I'm developing. Asyou'll see from the snippets I'm trying to use the mask as a logo for the home page. I'm still learning and I found this feature really interesting but when I execute the following code it simply displays a transparent image with the dimensions of the image src. I wrote this in CSS:

```
.agesciIcon {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: fit-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    mask-image: url(tiger.png);
    -webkit-mask-image: url(tiger.png);
    mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;

}
```

same result as

```
-webkit-mask: url(tiger.png);
mask: url(tiger.png);
```

and this in HTML:

```
<body>

        <section>
            <header>
                <img class="agesciIcon" src="mountMaskImg.jpg" alt="agesci icon">
                <h1>Montecelio 1</h1>
                <h3>Un'associazione di cent' anni</h3>
            </header>
```

obviuosly there's the closing body tag in my code but it would've been too long to include all the code

my tiger.png is actually a black and white png. I've seen all the possible tutorials but they all do the same as I coded. I tried to change the background image to a .avif (as I saw in a Kevin Powell's tutorial) but it didn't change at all

here are my 2 imgs if it helps
[tiger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqX6H.png)
[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXK08.jpg)

Comment: Both your linked images are the same one

Comment: Yeah sorry I just fixed it

Comment: I mean I fixed the question not the problem

Comment: don't use black/white, use opaque/transparent

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses **alpha channel** to process masks by default. Use the special property `mask-mode: luminance;` to use the color data of your image to mask.
Be aware tho that [it does not have a great overall support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_mask-mode) accross browsers.